# web view cannot open youtube link

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

i want to play youtube video in Titanium webview but it cannot play video .the link is http://www.chicagowolves.com/news?format=feed&type=rss  .and this link works in mac browser

and the error is

[ERROR] :  Error loading: , Error: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x78fbe6b0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.youtube.com/v/IKGPgnram1E?version=3&f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.youtube.com/v/IKGPgnram1E?version=3&
f=user_uploads&app=youtube_gdata, NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}

```
  function WebView(data) {
  var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
  backgroundColor : 'white',
  title : 'Videos',
  height : Ti.UI.FILL,
  width : Ti.UI.FILL

  });

   var webview = Titanium.UI.createWebView({
    url : data,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    backgroundColor : 'green'

    });
    self.add(webview);
    return self;
    }
    module.exports = WebView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var webView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + myVideoID + '?autoplay=1&autohide=1&cc_load_policy=0&color=white&controls=0&fs=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0',
    enableZoomControls: false,
    scalesPageToFit: false,
    scrollsToTop: false,
    showScrollbars: false
});

win.add(webView);

win.open();
```

I tried it before, it works fine, it's copied from this [link](https://gist.github.com/FokkeZB/5354066).